# How to check date range more than 6 months in php?

Tags: php, date, time

What I want to do is check the date range cannot more than 6 months, else will return false

**here is my sample code**

```
<?php
$date_string1 = "2013-01-01";
$date_string2 = "2013-08-01";
$date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_string1));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_string2));

if ($date1 and $date2 range more than 6 months, so will){
   return false;
}else{
   return true;
}
?>
```

**here is my GUI**

[image]

Any idea how to solve my problem? thanks

Comment: 6 month or 31/30*6 days?

Comment: Is it that hard? https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=php+date+difference

Comment: The Problem I see is that 6 months can be max ((4*31+2*30)*24+1)*60*60 (July AND August and DST = 15901200s and min ((28+3*31+2*30)*24-1)*60*60 = 15634800s

Comment: Using date->diff ain't gonna solve the problem to think about what you mean when you say "6 month range"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2013-01-01");
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "2013-08-01");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$diff = $interval->format('%m');

if($diff > 6){
 echo 'false';
}else{
 echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `diff` function

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-01-01');
$date2 = new DateTime('2013-08-01');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
$month = $diff->format('%m'); // 7

if ($month > 6){
   return false;
}else{
   return true;
}
```

#### Formats

```
%y year
%m month
%d day
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided wont work if the year has changed as the diff() provides a structure with the various components

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-10-02');
$date2 = new DateTime('2017-08-01');

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->y;   // prints '0'
echo $diff->m;   // prints '2'
//
$date1 = new DateTime('2017-10-02');
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-10-01');
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->y;   // prints '1'
echo $diff->m;   // prints '0'
```

The month calculation should be applied as :

```
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
$monthsDiff = $diff->y * 12 + $diff->m

if (monthsDiff > 6){
   return false;
}else{
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this -

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

//$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
//$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
//$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

if ($diff > 5184000) // more than 6 months
{
  return false;
}
else
{
  return true;
}
```